# Never Show Window On Page Launch

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using `C#` and `asp.net` to launch a webpage that I am passing parameters to. That works well!  I come from a `Windows.Forms` background so please forgive me if I am trying to achieve the impossible.  What I would like is set the `Visibility` property of the program (either IE or chrome) to false so the user never sees that a webpage is being launched.  I have been using this `JS` function to close the page, but it seems that the page must completely load before closing which sometimes can take a few seconds.

Does `asp.net` have the capability to achieve such?  And this is my `JS` code I have been using

```
string close = @"<script type = 'text/javascript'>
                    window.returnValue = true;
                    window.close();
                </script>";
base.Response.Write(close);
```

Comment: Why are you loading a page that the user does not see?  Can what you're wanting be done with code-behind or some other mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the User to see the page, I assume you just want to post some information to the page.  In that case, make an HTTP request via c# code, instead of opening the webpage up in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

On the Project Properties page, Web tab, Start Action section, click the radio button for "Don't open a page. Wait for a request from an external application".